# logger object in AbstractHealthIndicator is null - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, health-monitoring

When I call `heathIndicator.health()` method when database is down, it throws `NullPointerException`. Stack trace shows that `logger` object in **AbstractHealthIndicator** is null. I also verified it through debugging. Code works with no problem when database is up, because logger is not invoked. I didn't quite get why this can happen.

This is the code of `health` method in Spring's **AbstractHealthIndicator**

```java
@Override
    public final Health health() {
        Health.Builder builder = new Health.Builder();
        try {
            doHealthCheck(builder);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            // null pointer exception happens here, logger is null.
            if (this.logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
                String message = this.healthCheckFailedMessage.apply(ex);
                this.logger.warn(StringUtils.hasText(message) ? message : DEFAULT_MESSAGE,
                        ex);
            }
            builder.down(ex);
        }
        return builder.build();
    }
```

Comment: are you extending `AbstractHealthIndicator` ?, are you using spring-boot-2?

Comment: How are you initializing logger variable?

Comment: It is not my code, I am just using it. It is source code of `AbstractHealthIndicator`'s `health` method.

Comment: ohh, okay, got it, why are you worried about spring's internal code?, If you need to implement health check extend it and override method.

Comment: I mean it is doing exactly what I want, except for that portion. It is not even a logic problem, logger is just null for some reason. By the way, I know I can do my own implementation, but I am just curious why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with the `AbstractHealthIndicator` class. In my case the problem was using `@Transactional` inside my health indicator. Because of this annotation, Spring created a CGLIB proxy for my class. This shouldn't have to be a problem, but I guess because `AbstractHealthIndicator.health()` method inside the `AbstractHealthIndicator` is final the CGLIB proxy isn't working properly. The obvious solution for this is not using a `@Transactional` but delegating your check to a service.

This is also appointed during initializing. Something like this is logged:

```
 o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy: Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Health org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health()] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
```